# Creating variables based on values of another variable

Tags: sas

I have two groups, A and B, and two numeric variables, X and Y. I want to create two new variables, new1 and new2, based on the values of X and Y (respectively) for group B (i.e., IF group = B THEN new1 = X, new2 = Y). I want to take those newly created variables, append them to group A, and then delete group B. In the end, there should be one row for group A containing X, Y, new1, and new2. I'm uncertain how to accomplish this.

I've looked into using PROC TRANSPOSE, but I'm unsure if that's the right starting point. My internet searches are lacking because I'm not even sure what to call what I'm attempting to do, though I'm betting this is a common procedure requiring a common solution.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVzJv.png)

Comment: Can you demonstrate your question via an example that shows what you have and what you want.

Comment: I've added an example. Essentially what I'm after is whatever would be needed to transition from steps 2 to 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to generalize the problem, but for the given problem this will work:

```
/* Just reversing the records */
proc sort data = have; 
  by descending group;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  retain new1 new2;
  if _N_ = 1 then do;
    new1 = x;
    new2 = y;
  end;
  else output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case of 1 to 1 merging (merge with out `BY`).

```
data have; input 
group $1. x y; datalines;
A 3 4
B 2 6
run;

data want; 
  merge 
    have(where=( group='A'))
    have(where=(Bgroup='B') rename=(x=Bx y=By group=Bgroup))
  ;
  drop Bgroup;
run;
```